# ASP.NET MVC LCID and Sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lcid

i have to short questions on ASP MVC. Where is the best place
for setting on `Session.LCID` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In three places:

Upon login, inside the controller once successfully authenticated.

When they change their culture setting explicitly.

Before they are logged in you would base it on browser or ip address and [set in a base controller](http://helios.ca/2009/05/27/aspnet-mvc-and-localization/), reading from the session first to check if it's been set above.

Comment: okay, but why show an english page to german, french, etc before login? before login select by browser, then save by login, cookie etc. this doen't anwser the question.again, what is the best way and place in mvc framework to set the session. i dont want the controller because if someone calls another controller direct, i have to spread it over the whole code. must be easier way of doing this

Comment: base controller is the answer!